# Launching AWS spot instance with an old EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I do not now much about spot instances but I'm wondering whether I have to create a new EBS volume with every instance or is it possible to start an instance with a previously launched EBS volume ?

Answer (score 0):

Amazon provides an option to do the same.
[Delete on termination false spot instances](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ami-preserve-ebs-spot/)